# Synchronise real-time workshop in matlab for grt target

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I am trying to run a real-time simulation in Simulink using Real-time Workshop. The target is grt(I have tried rtwin, but my simulation refuses to compile for it). I need the simulation to run in real-time so that one second in simulation lasts one second of real time. Grt ignores realtime and finishes the simulation in shortest time possible. Is there any way to synchronise it?

I have tried http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3175 but could not get it to work(does not compile).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is impossible. I was able to slow down the execution by using Sleep(time in ms) function from WinApi and clock function from time.h, which looked quite good for low sample rates. However, when I increased the sample rate the Sleep function was sleeping for too long, which resulted in errors, with one second in simulation lasting more than one real world second.

The idea was to say that one period of iteration should last, let's say 200ms. Then time how long it takes for one iteration of code to execute using the clock function. Then call Sleep(200 - u), where u is the length of the iteration. The problem is that Sleep function sleeps the process and wakes it up when it wants to, not when you tell it to in the argument.

I know this is not a solution, but post this so that if anyone faces the same problem as me they won't try this dead-end solution. I had to rewrite the simulation for rtwin and now it works fine.

Another idea would be to somehow use interrupts, but I guess it would be quite complicated and not worth the trouble.